# (Done) Request to reopen after edit to narrow question scope

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/138237/how-to-conduct-a-hiring-interview-after-being-an-intern-for-6-month/138254#138254) is one vote away from being closed due to over - broad. I have edited the title and questions to hopefully narrow the scope and make them more focused on how to navigate job role assignment and discuss salary when working in **a niche / specialized** IT role such as cybersecurity.

Recently, our security operations team gained 2 new interns who appear promising and I would love to help retain them, possibly provide full time offer after the internship. The answers to this question would certainly help and I would love to see additional thoughts from the community.

Can we review the close votes after my edit?

Comment: What does "review the close votes" mean? If it actually gets closed, I'd be  happy to vote to reopen.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Question is closed. Did you vote to reopen?

Comment: I just voted to reopen. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

It's open now.  Thanks for the edits!